# Can I have more than 512 bytes in a disk sector read from a boot loader?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, sector

I'm making a bootloader which will of course be positioned on the 0th sector. Because of the limitation of only 512 bytes, which is the allowed size for the bootloader, I'm making it read the 1st sector, the sector right after the bootloader. Can the amount of information on the 1st sector be more than 512 bytes and still be read or do I have to specify for the computer to start reading the 3rd sector?

Comment: I know I should open my own question for this, but you seem to know the answer to my question. I'm new to assembly and am looking into booloaders and such. How did you load the first sector? Have a link to a resource?

Comment: I'm actually not that familiar with the topic. I would love to learn a lot about it though. I found a great series of tutorials which are a bit complex but in the end let you develop a simple OS. It was hard to find. Here's the link to the tutorial which shows you how to load the sectors. I suggest you read up on the previous ones, it can get quite confusing. http://brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev5.html

Comment: This has been possible historically with floppies, if relatively uncommon, e.g. <https://www.os2museum.com/wp/the-xdf-diskette-format/>. Support from virtualization software is virtually non-existent, though; only preservationist emulators like 86Box seem to have any support for non-512-byte sector floppy images, and you can probably forget about varying sector sizes for hard disks entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Each sector is 512, so if you want your bootload to obtain more than 512 bytes you actually need to load more sectors. Which sectors are actually available to you to keep the code or data, depends on partitioning schema, that is applied to the underlying disk (it will be different for MBR, GPT etc.).

Comment: I understand that but once I do read another sector of the disk and use that one up (write my programs on it) can I just keep writing my programs past the sector limit, into the third sector, or should I tell the program to, now, read the next sector?

Comment: @JohnMcTavish If I understand your question at all, you can only do I/O in integral number of integral sectors.